# Clean removal of View from ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

so i am trying to make flashcards for Android.

I decided to use ViewPager with PageAdapter.

I have a Question class that creates and stores views, so each question has it's own view. (question is flashcard). The UI of flashcard is inside ViewFlipper

There is also a class that extends Application. There i store my questions (flashcards) in ArrayList.

Here's my PageAdapter

```
class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LearnHelper app;
    int lastremoved = -1;

    public MyAdapter(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int i)
    {
        View view = app.getTmpQuestion(i).getViewingView(collection, mContext, i);
        if(collection.indexOfChild(view) == -1) {
            collection.addView(view);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int i, Object view)
    {
        app.getTmpQuestion(i).unbindListeners();
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return app.getTmpQuestionCount();
    }

    public void setApp(LearnHelper receivedapp) {
        app = receivedapp;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        View view = (View) object;
        if(lastremoved < 0) {return POSITION_UNCHANGED;}
        if(view.getId() >= lastremoved-1)
        {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
        else
        {
            return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
        }
    }

    public void setLastremoved(Integer i)
    {
        lastremoved = i;
    }

}
```

My adapter and viewpager being set

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
adapter.setApp(app);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

And two  methods, first one marks the question for deletion,second one removes it after slide to the next screen finishes.

```
public void hideQuestionCard(Question question) {
    question.MarkForDeletion();
    adapter.setLastremoved(app.tmpquestions.indexOf(question));
    MoveNext();
}

public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    if(state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        int currentitem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        if(currentitem == 0) {return;}
        Question question = app.getTmpQuestion(currentitem - 1);
        if(question.IsMarkedForDeletion()) {
            app.removeTmpQuestion(question);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

They work... only problem is, that this happens
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3jgzARMNYmRSkVwNV81bEZRSnc/view?usp=sharing

How can i make the card removal work nice and clean?

Comment: I am no longer working on that project because of this brick wall, if somebody knows how to avoid viewpager, i would like to hear it.